# Database not storing query

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

i am trying to run following code

```
        mDb.beginTransaction();

        String updateQuery ="INSERT INTO MAAccounts(userId, accountId, accountType, accountName, parentAccountId, currencyCode, isTransactionDefaultStatusOpen, currentBalance, monthlyBudget, createdOn, updatedOn) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
    String[] valVars = { 
            stringToDB(account.userId),
            integerToDB(account.accountId).toString(),
            integerToDB(account.accountType.getValue()).toString(),
            stringToDB(account.accountName), 
            integerToDB(account.parentAccountId),
            stringToDB(account.currencyCode),
            boolToDB(account.isTransactionDefaultStatusOpen).toString(),
            CurrencyToDB(account.currentBalance).toString(),
            CurrencyToDB(account.monthlyBudget).toString(),
            dateToDB(now),
            "false"};
  //  Cursor c = mDb.rawQueryWithFactory(null, updateQuery, valVars, null);
    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(updateQuery, valVars);
    try{ 
        mDb.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
       }catch (Exception e){
           Log.e("Error in transaction", e.toString());
       }finally{
           mDb.endTransaction();
           c.close();
           }
        }
```

The cursor it returns is null and even teh transaction is successful it won't store the data i have provided into the database.

My Primary key consists of `UserId, accountId, and accountType`

No exceptions are being recorded. Any idea where i am doing mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem.** Your exception handling is a bit confused. You want to be catching exceptions which happen *while executing your query*, rather than just managing the transaction. I suspect if you fix this, you'll see an exception being thrown.

It should look like this. Note that the query is now executed inside the `try {...}` block.

```
Cursor c = null;
mDb.beginTransaction();

try {
    c = mDb.rawQuery(updateQuery, valVars);
    mDb.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error in transaction", e.toString());
} finally {
    mDb.endTransaction();
    if (c != null)
        c.close();
}
```

**Second problem.** You are not *querying* the database; you are *inserting* data. This operation should not be expected to return a result, so `rawQuery()` is really the wrong thing to be using. You should investigate `execSQL()` instead, or use the `insert()` method which is much easier.

Comment: First problem is no problem, i have already tested that. How can i use Insert or execSQL? pls can you give me an example from above code?

Comment: `insert()` is better. See the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)

Comment: insert does not support sql statements.

Comment: That is correct. You should build up the list of name-value mappings in the `values` parameter instead.

Comment: execSQL worked but how can i get a result of , if the data has been entered or not any idea?

Comment: execSQL worked but how can i get a result of , if the data has been entered or not any idea?

Comment: It will throw an exception on failure.